# Error in Running R Shiny App: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am using Shiny and R to visualize my data interactively. I would like to draw an interactive scatter plot of Petal.Width versus Petal.Length in Iris dataset and cluster the points based on k clusters (user input) and p, the percentage of data rows dedicated to the training dataset (user input). I added a hover feature to the scatterplot so that by clicking on each point, the whole dataset for that point will be demonstrated.

The output should look like this:
[image]

```
# Loading Libraries
library(shiny)
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)


ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Clustering iris Data"),

  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("k", "Number of clusters:",
                min = 1, max = 5,  value = 3),

    sliderInput("prob", "Training percentage:",
                min=0.5, max=0.9, value = 0.7)),

  mainPanel(
  # img(src='iris_types.jpg', align = "center", height="50%", width="50%"),

  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  inTrain  <- createDataPartition(y=iris$Species, 
                                  p=input$prob, 
                                  list=FALSE)
  training <- iris[ inTrain,]
  testing  <- iris[-inTrain,]

  kMeans1 <- kmeans(subset(training,
                           select=-c(Species)),
                           centers=input$k)

  training$clusters <- as.factor(kMeans1$cluster)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    qplot(Petal.Width,
          Petal.Length,

          colour = clusters,
          data   = training,

          xlab="Petal Width",
          ylab="Petal Length")
  })

  output$info <- renderPrint({
    # With ggplot2, no need to tell it what the x and y variables are.
    # threshold: set max distance, in pixels
    # maxpoints: maximum number of rows to return
    # addDist: add column with distance, in pixels
    nearPoints(iris, input$plot_click, threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1,
               addDist = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run the app in R Studio, I receive the following error:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Comment: `input$prob` is a reactive value. You have to wrap your data in reactive content. For exemple with `reactiveValues()`

Comment: @Clemsang Thank you. Can you explain a little bit more? which line needs to change?

Comment: `inTrain`, `training`, `testing` are dynamic. You can create `reactiveValues` for each one in an `observe`. This way, you modify your 3 objects when the input change. You also have to change the call to these 3 objects with `reactiveValues$object_name` in the server when you can to use data. Look closer at `reactiveValues()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Clemsang you are using reactives values outside an `oberserver/render*` function.

What you want to do is to create a `reactive` environment, where you use your inputs. That is, something which gets recalculated whenever the inputs change. Thus, you need to wrap your training calculation in `reactive` and when you want to use it in your render function, you "call" it by adding `()`. I like to name my reactives with a verb, to highlight the fact that I actually do something when these functions are called, hence the name `get_training_data`:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  get_training_data <- reactive({ ## now your inputs are in a reactive environment
     inTrain  <- createDataPartition(y=iris$Species, 
                                     p=input$prob, 
                                     list=FALSE)
     training <- iris[ inTrain,]
     testing  <- iris[-inTrain,]

     kMeans1 <- kmeans(subset(training,
                              select=-c(Species)),
                       centers=input$k)

     training$clusters <- as.factor(kMeans1$cluster)
     training
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    qplot(Petal.Width,
          Petal.Length,

          colour = clusters,
          data   = get_training_data(),

          xlab="Petal Width",
          ylab="Petal Length")
  })

  output$info <- renderPrint({
    # With ggplot2, no need to tell it what the x and y variables are.
    # threshold: set max distance, in pixels
    # maxpoints: maximum number of rows to return
    # addDist: add column with distance, in pixels
    nearPoints(iris, input$plot_click, threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1,
               addDist = FALSE)
  })
}
```